# Can't find published extension when I'm searching for it inside Visual Studio Code (even by ID)

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have published a theme extension for Visual Studio Code here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TobiasDev.relaxed-dark, however, when I try to find it (even using @id:) it doesn't show up inside of Visual Studio Code so I can't install it.

I assume I have done something wrong or forgotten to add something. Does anyone here actually know what mistake I could have done?

I even can't install it when I download the VSIX file locally, which means it must be something I have done wrong. I followed the publishing page and even checked some other peoples theme to see if they have different info in their files, but I couldn't really see a big difference.

Thanks in advance!
Tobias Johansson

Comment: It shows up for me. https://i.imgur.com/cFE6VKB.png

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I have actually broken something in my VS Code then! I'll try to remove everything (including the user files), and hope that fixes it! Thanks for answering so quickly! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for other people looking for it, so it is probably something in my VS Code that is broken. Will do a clean install!